# df.drop is not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am very stuck with this, obviously I have little experience, so every opinion is welcome:

```
df = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(f,delimiter = '|') for f in onlyfiles)
# I have to delete the column 'Unnamed: 0'
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'])
df.head()
```

If somebody can tell something about this 'Unnamed: 0' column, I don't understand what's the use of this?

Thanks!

Comment: also is it possible that due the using of the `drop` the data frame converts into a Series?

Answer (score 4):

[**DOCS**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

`'Unnamed: 0'` is a column name.  You'll need to pass the `axis=1` parameter to `drop`

```
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1)
```

Because the `axis` parameter is the second parameter, that can be shortened to

```
df = df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], 1)
```

Comment: You can also utilize the `inplace=True` argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drop the column inplace, there's another way to do it.

```
del(df['Unnamed: 0'])
```